# numexpr: temporary variables or repeated sub-expressions?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, refactoring, numexpr

If the same sub-expression appears in multiple places within one *numexpr* expression, will it be recalculated multiple times (or is numexpr clever enough to detect this and reuse the result)?

Is there any way to declare temporary variables within a numexpr expression? This would have two aims:

1. encourage numexpr to consider caching and re-using, rather than re-calculating, the result;
2. simplify the expression (making the source code easier to read and maintain).

I am trying to calculate *f(g(x))* where *f* and *g* are themselves both complicated expressions (e.g. for pixel-based thematic classification, *f* is a nested decision tree involving multiple thresholds, *g* is a set of normalised difference ratios, and *x* is a multi-band raster image).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if a sub-expression is repeated within a numexpr expression, it will not be recalculated.

This can be verified by replacing `numexpr.evaluate(expr)` with `numexpr.disassemble(numexpr.NumExpr(expr))`.

For example, the expression `"where(x**2 > 0.5, 0, x**2 + 10)"` is compiled into something like:

```
y = x*x
t = y>0.5
y = y+10
y[t] = 0
```

(Note the multiplication only appears once, not twice.)

For this reason, it is best if the entire computation can be input as a single numexpression. Avoid performing sub-calculations in python (assigning intermediate results or temporary variables into numpy arrays), as this will only increase memory usage and undermine numexpr's optimisations/speedups (which relate to performing this full sequence of computations in CPU-cache sized chunks to evade memory latency).

Nonetheless, more readable code can be formatted by using string substitution:

```
f = """where({g} > 0.5,
             0,
             {g} + 10)"""
g = "x**2"
expr = f.format(g=g)
```